# How to pass the data between two component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React JS.

I want to trigger an event from one component to another component which is not having any parent and child relation.

Simply equals to `$broadcast` and `$emit` event in Angular 1.0

Please help me to go forward.

thanks,SrinivasaRao.CH

Comment: The question is too broad. There are various ways to do it in React either using middleware like redux or using state

Comment: You should definitely read the "get started" docs from [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) to understand how it is meant to work. The data flow has one direction only: top to bottom. In the docs, you will learn how to and where to define the state and data of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Use [redux](https://redux.js.org), where one component can fire an action which modifies the global store (global state) and another can access it.